# How to "add existing file" in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't find the "Resources->Add ->Existing Files" option. How do I do this?
Talking about Xcode 4.2

Comment: Add Files To "Project Name" from the File menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on any `Group` in the project tree..., you will find `Add files to ...`. The same entry is in the `Files` menu too.

Alternatively, if you didn't change key shortcuts, use `Cmd + Alt + A`.

Answer (score 0):

there's an "Add Files To ..." menu option when you right click. the resources folder has gone with xcode4 - you can create a group called Resources yourself and add any data to that. it's not necessary, but can be nice to have it organised that way. the main thing you want to check is that if you go to Project->Bundle Phases the resources you want copied should be in the "Copy Bundle Resources" list. if they aren't, you can drag and drop. xcode seems to be pretty smart about it, tho (famous last words).